# How do I grab a thumbnail screenshot of many websites?

Tags: python, perl, mechanize

I have a list of 2500 websites and need to grab a thumbnail screenshot of them. How do I do that?

I could try to parse the sites either with Perl or Python, Mechanize would be a good thing. But I am not so experienced with Perl.

Comment: You could sign up at snap.com and then use Perl to grab the snapshot images from them - check their Terms of Service first though

Answer (score 10):

Here is Perl solution:

```
  use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
  my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
  $mech->get('http://google.com');

  my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
```

From the docs:

> Returns the given tab or the current page rendered as
>   PNG image.
>
> All parameters are optional. $tab defaults to the current tab. If the
>   coordinates are given, that rectangle will be cut out. The coordinates
>   should be a hash with the four usual entries, left,top,width,height.
>
> This is specific to WWW::Mechanize::Firefox.
>
> Currently, the data transfer between Firefox and Perl is done
>   Base64-encoded. It would be beneficial to find what's necessary to
>   make JSON handle binary data more gracefully.

Comment: well - how to add the diff erent urls.. how if i do read them into from  a file. In other words i store the urls in a file... 

And afterwards i put out the results in another directory. 

what do you think?

Comment: Well i can quickly find this info in the Perl documentation: `perldoc -f open`