# read some variables out of a directory - in order to parse them with mechanize

Tags: perl, parsing, firefox, mechanize

I have a list of 2500 websites and need to grab a thumbnail screenshot of them. How do I do that? I could try to parse the sites either with Perl Mechanize - eg like this.

```
  use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
  my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
  $mech->get('http://google.com');

  my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
```

How do I do this for all of the different URLs? How do I read them from a file? In other words I store the URLs in a file. And afterwards I put out the results in another directory.

From the docs:

> Returns the given tab or the current page rendered as PNG image. All
>   parameters are optional. $tab defaults to the current tab. If the
>   coordinates are given, that rectangle will be cut out. The coordinates
>   should be a hash with the four usual entries,
>   left,top,width,height.This is specific to WWW::Mechanize::Firefox.

Comment: [Original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8381303) provided by SO user [gangabass](http://stackoverflow.com/u/347767).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand... you want to have a list of 2,500 URLs, one on each line, saved in a file.  Then you want your script above to open the file, read a line, then retrieve the website?  If so, something like this:

```
    Filename: urls.txt
    ------------------
    www.google.com
    www.cnn.com
    www.msnbc.com
    news.bbc.co.uk
    www.bing.com
    www.yahoo.com
```

Then the code:

```
    use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();

    open(INPUT, "urls.txt") or die "Can't open file: $!";

    while (<INPUT>) {
      chomp;
      $mech->get($_);
      my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
    }
    close(INPUT);
    exit;
```

Comment: Can the Mechanize `->new()` operation be hoisted out of the `while()` loop? Would that improve the performance of the script?

Comment: Indeed it would, good catch.  It only needs to be instantiated once.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: hi torgis hello samold - many many thanks for the great reply. i  test this. Sure with good results!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is in a file named `list.txt`:

```
open( my $fh, '<', 'list.txt') or die "Could not open list.txt: $!";
foreach my $url ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp $url;
    # Do your mechanize thing here using $url
}
close $fh;
```

Basically, open the file then loop through all of the lines in the file.

Comment: hi there - many many thanks for the great answer!! Overwhelming! i thank you. greetings.